# Time interval in thread

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

I have to simulate the roulette game for an exercise (without grade) our lecturer gave us. It have to be a multithreading client-server application. 
I'm designing the server (the client is quite simple, it only have to send the bet's requests) but I'm stuck.
I have two thread functions, 
the croupier: this one pull out numbers every N seconds (specified in command line) 
the player: this one read the number pulled out by the croupier and inserts bets in a shared list. Every player can bet one or more time.

My problem is: can I use a cond_timedwait to simulate the time interval between two numbers being pulled out? Is there another way to do this?

```
void *croupier(void *arg) {
struct timespec cond_time; 
time_t now; 
int status;
int intervallo = (int) arg;

//initializerand seed
srand(time(NULL));

while (1) {
    //lock mutex for number extraction
    status = pthread_mutex_lock(&puntate_mutex);
    if (status != 0) {
        err_abort(status, "Lock sul mutex nel croupier");
    }
    //number extraction
    estratto = rand() % 37;

    printf("CROUPIER estratto=%d\n", estratto);
    /* wake up players */
    status = pthread_cond_broadcast(&puntate_cond);
    if (status != 0) {
        err_abort(status, "Broadcast condition in croupier");
    }

    now = time(NULL);
    cond_time.tv_sec = now + intervallo;
    cond_time.tv_nsec = 0;
    //wait for condition
    while (estratto > 0) {
        status = pthread_cond_timedwait(&croupier_cond, &puntate_mutex, &cond_time);
        //if status == ETIMEDOUT, time is over
        if (status == ETIMEDOUT) {
            printf("CROUPIER time's over!!! Bets closed\n");
            estratto = -1; //bets closed
            break;
        }
        if (status != 0) {
            err_abort(status, "Timedwait croupier");
        }
    }

    printf("CROUPIER Gestisco la puntata\n");
    //TODO manage bets
    status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&puntate_mutex);
    if (status != 0) {
        err_abort(status, "Unlock sul mutex nel player");
    }
}
pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

void *player(void *arg) {
int num = (int) arg;
int letto = 0;
int status;

while (1) {
    status = pthread_mutex_lock(&puntate_mutex);
    if (status != 0) {
        err_abort(status, "Lock sul mutex nel player");
    }

    /* (estratto < 0) means that bets are closed */
    while (estratto < 0) {/* if bets are closed */
        printf("GIOCATORE %d CONDIZIONE FALSA\n", num);
        letto = 0;
        pthread_cond_wait(&puntate_cond, &puntate_mutex); //TODO inserire gestione errori
    }

    //here player can bet
    /*???????
     * read bet on socket
     * insert bet in list
     * */

    status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&puntate_mutex);
    if (status != 0) {
        err_abort(status, "Unlock sul mutex nel player");
    }
}
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: comments in English language would help..

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be simpler to just use sleep() or usleep() to pause the thread the requisite interval.

---

update:

Simply unlock the mutex before sleeping, and lock it again when you wake.

Think of the mutex as protecting access to `estratto` -- you want to have the mutex locked only as long as you are modifying/reading that shared value. So:

```
lock()
estratto = rand() % 37;
unlock()
```

In particular, note that:

- you generally do not want to be doing terminal IO (printf) while holding a mutex (if that IO is blocked because of network flow control, any other threads that need the mutex will get locked up too)
- you don't need to lock the mutex to do `pthread_cond_broadcast`

Comment: The reason for using pthread_cond_timedwait is that I need some way to regain the mutex and stop all players when the time is out: how I can do this using sleep?

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions (especially the terminal IO one) but I can't find a way to make it work. If I only sleep() the thread how can I stop the other threads betting when the time interval is passed?